# Google ClientLogin authorization for multiple services

Tags: google-authentication

in the HTTPS request sent to Google ClientLogin https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin

i send a parameter with https request named "service". this will be the Google service i need to authenticate with.

in my application i want to be granted access to both "contacts" and "google docs" services. can i send two "service" parameters request to ClientLogin? one for each service? will this work or is there another more clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

[According to a Google employee](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/google-contacts-api/GbtR0JGgH5o/LKoJf8S5vgkJ) it is not possible to get a token that is valid for multiple services:

```
A Client Login token only works for a single service, but you can 
request more than one token. For example one for Calendar (cl) and 
another for Contacts (cp) then you can use the appropriate token for 
the following services requests.
```

I can't find anything in the documentation about getting multiple tokens for different services with only one request so I think the cleanest way is probably just doing 2 requests and keeping the 2 tokens.